# Select rows of joined values using MAX

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, max

Consider the following schema.

Student:

```
StudentID uniqueidentifier
Name varchar(max)
FKTeacherID uniqueidentifier
```

TestScore:

```
TestScoreID uniqueidentifier
Score int
FKStudentID uniqueidentifier
```

My goal is to write a query that yields each teacher's highest test score and the student that achieved it. Returning the teacher's id (Student.FKTeacherID), the score that was achieved (TestScore.Score) and the student that achieved it (Student.Name).

I can write something like this to get the first two required columns:

```
SELECT FKTeacherID, MAX(Score) MaxScore
FROM Student
JOIN TestScore on FKStudentID = StudentID
GROUP BY FKTeacherID
```

But I can't obtain the relevant Student.Name without adding it to the group by clause, which would change the result set.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, one option is to use `row_number()` -- here's an example with a common-table-expression:

```
with cte as (
    select s.fkteacherid,
        ts.score,
        s.name,
        row_number() over (partition by s.fkteacherid order by ts.score desc) rn
    from student s
        inner join testscore ts on s.studentid = ts.fkstudentid
)
select fkteacherid, score, name
from cte
where rn = 1
```

The basic idea is to group by `fkteacherid`, ordering by the `score desc` within each group, and taking the first record from each group.

Comment: Thank you, it fulfills the functional requirement. Only problem is that the cte evaluates the row number for every record, even if the column we are ordering by is indexed. In theory it is not necessary to do this in order to determine the results, I wonder if there is a way that forces SQL to evaluate the same result set but more efficiently...

Comment: @PatrickM -- I imagine using this analytic function will produce your best execution plan, but as always when it comes to performance, you'll need to test on your own (make sure you have the appropriate indices).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Please try the updated query if you might:

```
SELECT 
    FKTeacherID, Name, Score
FROM 
    Student
    JOIN TestScore on FKStudentID = StudentID
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            B.FKTeacherID AS TeacherID, MAX(A.Score) MaxScore 
        FROM 
            Student B
            JOIN TestScore A on A.FKStudentID = B.StudentID
        GROUP BY    
            B.FKTeacherID
    ) As TeachersMaxScore
    ON TeachersMaxScore.TeacherID = FKTeacherID 
       AND TeachersMaxScore.MaxScore = Score
```

Comment: The subquery `SELECT MAX(A.Score) MaxScore FROM TestScore A` returns only one record; the max score of all TestScore records. I need each max Score per Teacher

Comment: This may return duplicate FKTeacherID values, which violates my requirement